# Cycling through multiple lists in shell for loop

Tags: shell

There is a way to do this in python using itertools.product, but, is there a way to do this in shell?

```
L1 = 'a b c'
L2 = '1 2'
L3 = 'x y'

for x, y, z in L1, L2, L3:
do
   echo x,y,z
done
```

I would like the results to look like:

```
a1x
a1y
a2x
a2y
b1x
b1y
...
```

Comment: @oguzismail I don't know how to do it in shell, that is why I asked the question and put the "shell" tag. But, I'll change the code to look shell like.

Answer (score 3):

If you know what the lists are, you can use brace expansion:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {a,b,c}{1,2}{x,y}
a1x
a1y
a2x
a2y
b1x
b1y
b2x
b2y
c1x
c1y
c2x
c2y
```

If, however, the lists are in, say, three arrays, you have to do nested loops:

```
l1=(a b c); l2=(1 2); l3=(x y)
for i in "${l1[@]}"; do
    for j in "${l2[@]}"; do
        for k in "${l3[@]}"; do
            echo "$i$j$k"
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: This works, but I just realized that my example isn't correct, my apologies. I will edit it.